# Python / Pandas - KeyError merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

I have two dataframes I'm trying to merge:

```
target:

    version  city_id            code
id                                                                            
4         2        4   5736201000175   
26        2        3   8290265000183   
27        3        3   9529184000156   
30        3        3   9263064000150   
34        2        3   9312770000144   
54        1        3   8407830000140   
55        1        3   5590100000139   



city:

    federation_unit_id       name
id                                        
3                    8  SAO PAULO
4                    8   CAMPINAS
7                    8    BARUERI
8                    8  BEBEDOURO
9                    8     SANTOS
```

I want to merge them combining `target`'s "city_id" with `city`'s "id", in a way that the final dataframe looks like this:

```
target:

    version  city_id            code    federation_unit_id       name
id                                                                            
4         2        4   5736201000175                     8   CAMPINAS
26        2        3   8290265000183                     8  SAO PAULO
27        3        3   9529184000156                     8  SAO PAULO
30        3        3   9263064000150                     8  SAO PAULO
34        2        3   9312770000144                     8  SAO PAULO
54        1        3   8407830000140                     8  SAO PAULO
55        1        3   5590100000139                     8  SAO PAULO
```

To achieve that, I'm trying to use the following code:

```
target=target.merge(city, left_on='city_id', right_on='id')
```

However it keeps getting me the following KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/file.py", line 12, in <module>
target=target.merge(city, left_on='index', right_on='city_id')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4437, in merge
copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 38, in merge
copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 210, in __init__
self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 434, in _get_merge_keys
right_keys.append(right[rk]._values)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3290, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'id'
```

I can't find out what am I doing wrong :/
Can someone help on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` in the *city* data frame seems to be an index, try set `right_index=True`:

```
target.merge(city, left_on='city_id', right_index=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use [**`join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
target.join(city, on='city_id')
```

---

`join` is inherently index oriented. However, you can specify an alternative column to join on in the dataframe that constitutes the left side. If we call the `join` method on `target` then we want to specify `'city_id'` as that alternative column. The `city` dataframe already has the appropriate index.